# In github, how can I see who changed the tag?

Tags: git, github

How can I see who changed the tag for a build if they did not leave a message ?
I can't seem to find this anyway, nor is Google any help.

Answer (score 1):

Is `git show <tag-name>` what you are looking for? Example output below. Don't know how you can see it in Github tough.

```
$ git show v2.2.0
tag v2.2.0
Tagger: Some guy <some.guy@example.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 10 09:50:59 2014 +0200

v2.2.0
```

**Edit**
Found the same information in Github. Click releases, and then a tag.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases/tag/1.11.1

Comment: In general it is exceedingly bad practice to change any tag that has been publicly pushed. The information that "v2.2.0" used to be something else, and may actually be built and deployed as THAT OTHER THING is completely lost, leading to support and Q/A nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the information associated with a tag with the [GitHub V3 API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), with [the tag API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/).

You can also:

- monitor the [create/delete events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#createevent) in order to catch any event regarding tagging on your GitHub repo.
- [list a repo events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events) in order to find events for tags in the past history of your repo.